# How to use Autolayout and self-sizing cells in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have setup the auto-sizing cells with UILabels with no problem in iOS8 following this tutorial:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html

But I am having problems setting up a UIImageView using auto-sizing.  I need the images to be different sizes in Landscape compared to portrait (so they retain the same aspect ratio).  But each time I get a broken layout constraints error

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14554680 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x14564440(200)]>
```

As the actual code has quite a few different types of cell (that all work with auto-sizing cells) I have setup a simple example of the issue with a blue image view here:

https://github.com/AdrianMW/ios8autosizingCells

I have setup the constraints to the superview and am setting up the height like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ImageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kImageCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = [self heightForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    return cell;
}
```

**Solutions Tried**

I have tried turning off setTranslatesAutosizingMask: on the cell as per some of the other suggestions but when I do I just get a blank space instead of a image.  I have also tried adding the following:

```
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

I have seen mention of overriding sizethatfits: to get it to work on this cell using the old way but that doesn't seem to be called on the cell.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your ImageTableViewCell.xib, try changing the constraint:

```
Image View.Bottom EQUAL Superview.Bottom
```

Change the priority from 1000 to 999.